# Firebase - Query Child of Child

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have following Firebase Realtime Database structure.

[image]

I want to search a game with inviteCode = 271429. **There are multiple categories, so I don't have a way to know if this particular invite code will fall under *Maths*.**

I tried using .orderByChild() but that doesn't work on child of child. It works only if I know that I need to look in Maths.

I tried to look for a way if I could only get keys of 'games' and then I could loop in those keys looking for the code. I ended up finding [shallow](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow) but it seems it is available for REST only. I am trying to implement this in Flutter.

I don't want to download the complete data and then search because the data size can be large.

What is the best possible solution to query such a database structure? Should I improve the database structure? Keep in mind the need to limit the number of calls to database to avoid excessive data calls because I believe Firebase charges based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries work on a flat list of nodes. The key/value you are ordering/filtering on must be at a fixed path directly under each direct child node of the location you search.

The simplest solution here seems to be to add an additional data structure that maps the `inviteCode` values back to their category (and possibly other data about them). This is sometime referred to as a inverted index, and is quite common in NoSQL databases.

So you'd have:

```
invoteCodesLookup: {
  "271429": {
    category: "Maths",
    ...
  }
}
```

You can keep this and the original data structure in sync with multi-path updates and security rules.

For more on this, see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [Firebase simple many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130311/firebase-simple-many-to-many-relationship)
- [Many to many relationships on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981358/many-to-many-relationships-on-firebase)
- [How do I load/retrieve a Many to Many relationship in Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345673/how-do-i-load-retrieve-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase-realtime-database)